# Selenium: Count Classes with the same name

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, class

I am trying to count each class with the name [product unlocked enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZd29.png)
I have it set on a time looped to recount, grabbing a larger value as more classes change their name.

However, after lots of googling, I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbRGl.jpg) code.
However the count never reaches past -1. (0 before the minus 1)

Even when [more than one class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHY4x.jpg) changes to product unlocked enabled.

I've been googling and trying different solutions. However I think i might be tackling this the wrong way as no one else has really come across this problem.

Comment: Please paste the code here. Image does not help with debugging

Answer (score 0):

Due to the absence of code here, first of all, check whether your XPath locator is valid. You can use a handy Chrome plugin "ChroPath" to do that:

[image]